# TIMESTAMPDIFF alias in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I recently switched to using postgreSQL and I am having same difficulties finding an alternative for `timestampiff`

My original query was something like

```
select a.column_a, a.column_b, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_MINUTE, a.TIME_START, now()) AS "Time_diff"
from table as a
where 
...
```

I can do just `( now() - a.TIME_START)` but i want to show the result in minutes. Is there any better alternatives in postgresql to do the subtraction from now and show the result just as minutes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`now() - a.TIME_START` returns an `interval` which can be [converted](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to seconds using `extract()` and those can be converted to minutes:

```sql
extract(epoch from now() - a.time_start) / 60 as diff_minutes
```

---

If you don't need it as a number, another option is to simply format the interval to show minutes and seconds

```
to_char(now() - a.time_start, 'mi:ss')
```

Note that this will hide the information if the interval was bigger than 60 minutes (or bigger than a day). If that can happen as well, maybe you want to use `'dd hh24:mi:ss'` as a format mask instead

Comment: Now i get it. thank you for clarifying :) .Have an awesome day